# Dynamic params reconstruct

Tags: java, parameters

I want to use spring mvc controller to get user input command & args and then invoke sendCommand method.

Invoke url like：

```
http://127.0.0.1:8090/offheap/cmd?command=set a 1 b 2 c 3
```

The controller will accept below command as string.

> set a 1 b 2 c 3

Then it will invoke sendCommand method to set key a, value 1; key b, value 2; key c, value 3 into local cache.

Controller code below:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/offheap/cmd")
public String userInput(@RequestParam String command) {

    String[] commandArray = command.split(" ");
    String cmd = StringUtils.upperCase(commandArray[0]);

    Object result;

    if (commandArray.length > 1) {
        //TODO, how to construct the args??
        byte[][] args = null;
        result = ohcCacheStrategy.sendCommand(OffheapCacheCommand.valueOf(cmd), args);
    } else {
        result = ohcCacheStrategy.sendCommand(OffheapCacheCommand.valueOf(cmd));
    }
    return JSON.toJSONString(result);
}
```

SendCommand method code below:

```
public Object sendCommand(OffheapCacheCommand command, byte[]... args) {
    //logic here, will ignore.
}
```

I konw for byte[]...args, one shold construct a byte[][] array contains the data you want to pass to sendCommand method.

But the problem is that the byte[][] array is hard to construct.

Would anyone have good ideas to contruct this byte[][] array?

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: @RaymondChen Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it per below code.

```
 public String sendCommand(@RequestParam String command, @RequestParam String args) {

    String cmd = StringUtils.upperCase(command);
    String[] argsArray = args.split(" ");
    Object result;

    if (argsArray.length > 0) {
        byte[][] byteArray = new byte[argsArray.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < argsArray.length; i++) {
            byte[] element = SerializationUtils.serialize(argsArray[i]);
            byteArray[i] = element;
        }

        result = ohcCacheStrategy.sendCommand(OffheapCacheCommand.valueOf(cmd), byteArray);
    } else {
        result = ohcCacheStrategy.sendCommand(OffheapCacheCommand.valueOf(cmd));
    }
    return JSON.toJSONString(result);
}
```